# How to combine the index function with multiple criteria?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am having trouble figuring out an index function. My datasheet is as follows

Tab 1 - complete list of all subcompanies held by all holding companies 
- The first column shows holding companies
- the second column shows the subcompanies held by each holding company
- the third, fourth and fifth column give the key financials of these subcompanies (EBITDA)

The tabs after Tab 1 are tabs for every holding company. In these tabs I have a section where I want to only include the subcompanies from Tab 1 with an EBITDA higher than 20 million

Example:
Holding company A has the following subcompanies: Sub1 (EBITDA:10m), Sub2 (EBITDA: 21m), Sub3 (EBITDA: 15m).

In the tab of company A I want to only display the information of Sub2 as it meets the minimum threshold

The function I have now displays all information of each subcompany per holding company regardless of their EBITDA:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Tab1!D$5:D$337,SMALL(IF(Tab1!$C$5:$C$337=$C$6,ROW(Tab1!D$5:D$337)-MIN(ROW(Tab1!D$5:D$337))+1),ROWS(B$55:B55))),"")`

Tab1 Column D has all the subcompany names
Tab1 Column C has all holding company names
Column B is where I insert the subcompanies in the holding company tab

The output provides all subcompanies per holding, but I only want the subcompanies per holding with an EBITDA equal or larger than 20m

How can I add a criteria to filter if one or more of the 3 years worth of EBITDAs (Tab1 Column N, O & P) per subcompany is equal or larger than 20m?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change the criteria in the IF statement from:

`Tab1!$C$5:$C$337=$C$6`

to also check columns N, O or P being over 20m:

`(Tab1!$C$5:$C$337=$C$6)*((Tab1!$N$5:$N$337>20000000)+(Tab1!$O$5:$O$337>20000000)+(Tab1!$P$5:$P$337>20000000))`

Comment: The last range should be (Tab1!$P$5:$P$337>20000000) instead of (Tab1!$O$5:$O$337>20000000))

Comment: Well spotted, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `FormulaArray`, however, you could also use this standard formula *(entered at `B6`)*:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Tab1'!$D$5:$D$337,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW(B:B) /
( ( 'Tab1'!$C$5:$C$337 = $C$6 ) *
( ( 'Tab1'!$N$5:$N$337 > 20 ) + ( 'Tab1'!$O$5:$O$337 > 20 ) + ( 'Tab1'!$P$5:$P$337 > 20 ) <> 0 ) ),
ROWS( B$5:B5 ) ) ), "" )
```